# Range matching with anniversaries

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get records which any of `starts_at` column anniversaries matches with a range period, but not with `ends_at` one.

For instance, we have this `subscriptions` table:

| id | starts_at | ends_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-01-01 | 2016-01-01 |
| 2 | 2014-01-01 | 2017-01-01 |

And for range `2015-12-01` to `2016-02-01`.

I will need the one with `ID: 2` because one of its anniversaries `(2016-01-01)` is in range but `ends_at` is not.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56544c/2)

Comment: The record with ID of 2 does not match the query - its `starts_at` column is outside the given range `2015-12-01 : 2016-02-01`

Answer (score 3):

Create a year lookup table like below and insert rows based on your data(say 1980 to 2050):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `year_lookup` (
  `year_value` int,
  PRIMARY KEY (`year_value`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  

INSERT INTO `year_lookup` (`year_value`) VALUES
  ('2010'),
  ('2011'),
  ('2012'),
  ('2013'),
  ('2014'),
  ('2015'),
  ('2016'),
  ('2017');
```

Then, join the subscription table with yearlookup to find all possible anniversary. Finally, filter the records based on starts_at `BETWEEN` and end_at `NOT BETWEEN` as below.

```
-- Anniversary
SELECT DISTINCT Final.id FROM (
  SELECT s.id AS id, DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(y.year_value, 1), INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(starts_at)-1 DAY) AS starts_at, ends_at 
  FROM subscriptions AS s
  INNER JOIN year_lookup AS y
      ON y.year_value BETWEEN YEAR(starts_at) AND YEAR(ends_at)
  ) AS Final
WHERE    
   ((starts_at BETWEEN '2015-12-01' AND '2016-02-01') 
     AND (ends_at NOT BETWEEN '2015-12-01' AND '2016-02-01')) ;
```

Refer this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2e4bc/5)

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to create that `year_lookup` on the fly. Or it is necessary to create the table?

Comment: It will be faster if it is a physical indexed table.

Comment: @ananth_mk Actually it does not take account of starts_at and ends_at properly. Look, if I change range with one previous to starts_at it takes it because one of the years from 2010 matches with range. But it should make loop only from starts_at to ends_at anniversaries. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2e4bc/6)

Comment: I think with this is fine. Tell me what you think [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2e4bc/26)